# How to know if SQLAlchemy database migrations were done correctly on heroku?

Tags: python, database, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I am developing an application with python, flask and using SQLAlchemy as the database.

On my local machine the code is working perfectly, when I deployed it to heroku I got the error `The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application`.

Then I noticed that I hadn't done the database migrations, so I searched the internet and found this material: [Setting up flask app in heroku with a database](https://gist.github.com/mayukh18/2223bc8fc152631205abd7cbf1efdd41/). I followed it step by step, but I still had the same initial problem.

To find out in more detail what the error was I tried to implement a `log file`, but it didn't work.

```
from logging import FileHandler,WARNING

file_handler = FileHandler('errorlog.txt')
file_handler.setLevel(WARNING)
```

How can I get more information about this error that came up or to know if the SQLAlchemy database is working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Log to `stdout` or `stderr`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log), e.g.

```py
from logging import StreamHandler, WARNING

stream_handler = StreamHandler()  # Defaults to sys.stderr
stream_handler.setLevel(WARNING)
```

The output will be included in the Heroku's [standard log stream](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#runtime-logs), which you [can view by running `heroku logs` or the dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs).